# NGINX redirecting clean URL to index.php

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

Given an URL like so:

```
www.example.com/path/data
```

Which should be parsed by index.php like so:

```
www.example.com/?path&q=data
```

But should appear in the browser like so:

```
www.example.com/path/data
```

How is this best configured in NGINX?

I've attempted (among others):

```
location = /path {
    try_files $uri$is_args$args =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

But this seems to simply reach /path and not pass the GET parameters through to index.php

I feel I'm overlooking something quite simple, but can't seem to wrap my head around how this should be done. I've tried various solutions in a rewrite as well, but without success.

To put the problem differently: I want the GET parameters to be parsed by index.php, but I want the URL to remain clean in the browser.

For context, this regards a WordPress installation.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /path/index.php?options=$1 [L]

Comment: That would be Apache config. Also, are you sure this would actually keep the URL clean?

Comment: _“For context, this regards a WordPress installation.”_ - explanations on how to set up default WP routing on nginx instead of apache are available online. I can’t tell right now whether you need only that, or whether you want to do something “outside” of WP here.